# A proof that $\int_{-1}^1\frac1xdx=0$

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification, fake-proofs

I was inspired by BlackPenRedPen's [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dHwrzLDmdT8) about why $$\int_{-1}^1\frac1xdx$$ doesn't exist. However, I was able to prove the following claim which gives the above integral as $0$. I want to know what is wrong with my proof:

> Claim: Let $f(x)$ be continuous in the interval $[a,b]$ except for an asymptote $a<c<b$. Additionally, $f(x+c)=-f(-x+c)$. Then, $$\int_a^b f(x)dx=\int_{2c-a}^b f(x)dx$$Proof: Using the fact that $f(x+c)=-f(-x+c)$, it follows that $$\int_a^{c-\epsilon}f(x)dx=-\int_{c+\epsilon}^{2c-a}f(x)dx\tag{1}$$Where $\epsilon$ is chosen to be small. We also have that $$\int_a^bf(x)dx=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0}\left(\int_a^{c-\epsilon}f(x)dx+\int_{c+\epsilon}^bf(x)dx\right)\tag{2}$$The second integral on the RHS can be written as $$\int_{c+\epsilon}^bf(x)dx=\int_{c+\epsilon}^{2c-a}f(x)dx+\int_{2c-a}^bf(x)dx$$Substituting this into $(2)$, we have that $$\int_a^bf(x)dx=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0}\left(\int_a^{c-\epsilon}f(x)dx+\int_{c+\epsilon}^{2c-a}f(x)dx+\int_{2c-a}^bf(x)dx\right)=\int_{2c-a}^bf(x)dx$$The last equality follows from $(1)$.

Substituting $c=0$ and $f(x)=\frac1x$ into the claim, we get that the very first integral is zero.

An important thing to note is that BlackPenRedPen turned the integral into two limits, while I had one limit in my proof. I think this is what is wrong, but why?

Comment: I didn't look too closely at your proof, but even if it may be right, it cannot be applied to your function as $x\mapsto \frac{1}{x}$ is not continuous on $[-1,1]$.

Comment: The integral in question doesn't even exist, so formal manipulations of it aren't very meaningful.  The point of the "two limits" presumably is to try to work with the integral in regions where it does exist and then see what happens if you try to "extend" over the singularity.

Comment: The issue is that the limit of the sum of the first two integrals is not the same as the integral from $a$ to $2c-a$

Comment: @stange look at his Claim more closely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've had some comments already but I'd like to point out what I consider to be the main "error":

> We have that: $$\tag{2}\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\lim_{\epsilon\to0\color{red}{^+}}\left(\int_a^{c-\epsilon}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x+\int_{c+\epsilon}^bf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\right)$$

This is false. In fact, the right hand side describes the *principal value* integral which **does** exist (and equal zero) for $f: x\mapsto1/x$.

Instead, in the standard treatments of improper Riemann integration, we demand the following limit to exist: $$\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+\\\delta\to0^+}\left(\int_a^{c-\delta}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x+\int_{c+\epsilon}^bf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\right)\tag3$$And then we call *this* the integral. This *double* limit does **not** exist for $f:x\mapsto1/x$.

Comment: Note:  Why do we not use $(2)$ rather than $(3)$ as the definition for the improper integral?  Because some useful properties of integrals (such as change of variables) may fail for that definition.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So I can say that $\text{P.V.}\int_a^bf(x)dx=\int_{2c-a}^bf(x)dx$?

Comment: @KamalSaleh Yes, I think you can